# Bootstrap table row actions

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-table

What is the best way to add column with actions (buttons, links) to bootstrap table if it gets data via url?

Now I use custom formatter but it looks ugly:

```
<th data-formatter="actionsFormatter"></th>
```

...

```
function actionsFormatter(value, row) {
    return "<a class=\"btn btn-xs btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></a>";
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jaganathan/R2Her/

Comment: I want to use actions "in row", not from toolbar.

Comment: That does, the function actionsFormatter is set on the column but runs per row.